# Is it possible to send email from local linux machine to internet?

Tags: linux, sendmail, mta

I have a linux machine running at home. I installed sendmail as MTA. But I can't send email outside to internet email addresses.

I am not sure whether it's because the config of my sendmail or internet MTA refuses the delivery from my "unknown" MTA?

In another word, do I have to own an internet domain to setup a "send-only" mail sever at home?

Any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your network provider is restricting outgoing mail, as it is frequently a sign of a spammer or a compromised machine. If you find the instructions from your provider for configuring an email client for their network, you should be able to configure sendmail (or other MTA) the same way. This will probably involve using your username and password to authenticate with their SMTP server as the next hop to connect to. This may be called "[smarthost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host)" in your MTA config.

If you have a specific error that you are seeing though, it could be completely unrelated.